# Why the Alegreya font doesn't display correctly in some browsers?

Tags: html, css, webfonts

I use the following minimal HTML code for reproducing the problem:

```html
<html>

<body>
  <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Alegreya&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">

  <style>
    body {
      font-family: "Alegreya"
    }
  </style>

  <h1>Testing the web font Alegreya</h1>
  Testing the web font Alegreya
</body>

</html>
```

The document is displayed like this:
[image: Opera output]

As you can see, there is a weird outline around some letters. This behavior appears only for H1 tags *and* only for the webfont Alegreya. In normal text, it works. With another font, it works. With the Alegreya font installed on the system, it works too. It has to be downloaded as a webfont to see the bug.

Tested on Windows 10, on two computers. It doesn't work on Opera, Edge and Chrome. It *does* work on IE and Firefox though.

What's happening here?

Comment: Rendering on Linux with Chrome 91.0.4472.114 is a bit "muddy" too. If the problem exists in Opera, Edge and Chrome, it smells like Blink is messing up the font rendering. (They are all basically Chromium browsers)

Comment: Yeah and even better, if one runs your example here in the page using Chrome and then zooms the page in and out, different letters break or work properly. They screw up in a way that's reminiscent of the results of poor work in an SVG editor. When doing svgs, solid black text shouldn't have an outline - it should have no outline and solid fill. There appears to be the same nonsense going on with this font..

Comment: I thought so, too. But why only for the H1 tags? When zooming on the normal text, no distortion occurs...

Comment: @Stamm - it isn't. Copied your code to a new answer, altered it to using H2 tags - still happens. Perhaps there's a copy of the font specifically for Hnn tags.

Comment: @Stamm - Just tried dropping the text into a div and setting the font-size to 96px. No more screwed-up outline. ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same issue. It seems related to the font-weight applied.
I fixed it by specifying explicitly the font weight(s) to be loaded in the URL.
See the code snippet below.

```html
<html>

<body>
  <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Alegreya:wght@400;700&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">

  <style>
    body {
      font-family: "Alegreya"
    }
  </style>

  <h1>Testing the web font Alegreya</h1>
  Testing the web font Alegreya
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Yes, it works! Thank you very much!